# Соответствие вопросов о HTML и CSS тематике сайта

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, тематика

[**Страница справки**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). В разделе *«Какие вопросы можно задавать?»* не нашёл пункта о соответствии тематике сайта вопросов про не являющиеся языками программирования HTML и CSS (а также XML, LESS и т. д.) в случае, если не затрагивается использование JavaScript (или, к примеру, CoffeeScript, Dart).

Тем не менее подобные вопросы по вёрстке задаются, и если они не нарушают правил, то никто их не закрывает. я что-то недопонял, правила нуждаются в дополнении, или же эти вопросы всё-таки не разрешены?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HTML и CSS являются языками программирования в широком смысле этого слова, просто они (вероятно) не обладают [Полнотой по Тьюрингу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%A2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83).

Точно так же на сайте уместны вопросы о языках разметки и форматах данных Markdown, YAML (Yaml Ain't Markup Language!), XML, JSON и т.п.

Comment: > Если на сомнения вас навёл этот вопрос. — Нет, этот вопрос никак не связан с HTML или CSS, если и выскажу соображения о нём, то не в контексте данного обсуждения. Спасибо.