# Систематизация книг и учебных материалов по вёрстке

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, учебные-материалы

Давно хотел поднять вопрос о систематизации книг связанных с вёрсткой. Понаблюдав более года за вопросами касательно литературы по HTML/CSS, вижу (со своей колокольни), что есть необходимость отделить [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8) по [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)[css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) в отдельный пункт вопроса [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), так как в основном, все что связано с версткой в большинстве случаев дублируют каждый раз по-разному. Иногда к [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) , иногда дублируют как предыдущие закрытые вопросы по данной тематике, а порой просто игнорят, так как не знают к чему это прицепить. Я понимаю, что значение [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) возможно не столь существенно, как к примеру любого языка программирования (хотя по этому поводу вопрос как-то поднимался [Соответствие вопросов о HTML и CSS тематике сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2984/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be-html-%d0%b8-css-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0)), но все-таки большинство из нас, пользуется ими ежедневно.

А уже из этого вопроса, соответственно исходит и еще один связанный по [svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg), куда его? К этим двум, или отдельно? Как пример отдельного вопроса, есть: [Книги и учебные материалы по SVG.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784137/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-svg)

Есть куча примеров и связанных тегов. Думаю, суть я вкратце изложил.
**Поделитесь пожалуйста своим мнением по этому поводу.**

*UPDATE:*
 Были внесены изменения и добавлен новый топик по [Книгам и учебным материалам по SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/784137/262779). Есть ещё вопрос по [canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas), как тоже смежной технологии.

Comment: [Сделал новый вопрос, как и обсуждали.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924441/262779)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте придубликатим [книги по css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/8516/213987) в [книги по html+css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/213987) и постепенно перенесём все книги по css в более [общий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/213987).

Аргументы "за":

- Темы очень близкие и вопросы по css во многом невозможны без знаний по html

Answer (score 2):

Я забрёл в эту тему из очередей проверок, когда завис над [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/305512) "а не стоит ли придубликатить [книги по css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/8516/213987) в [книги по html+css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/213987)", а оттуда уже набрёл на эту тему.

В ней несмотря на заплюсованность нет ни одного ответа - хотя прошёл уже почти месяц с момента открытия. Давайте всё-таки обсудим вопрос по-существу.

Есть [общий рубрикатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/213987) в котором приведены ссылки на наши вопросы-о-книгах. Влад туда ссылку на книги по html+css уже добавил - это бесспорно шаг правильный и нужный и формально он мог и не начинать тему на мете, сразу добавить.

Я полагаю, что всем очевидно, что javascript должен идти отдельной темой (это слишком большая часть и её нужно отдельно) -- и это всегда так и есть.

Я полагаю, что так же очевидно, что svg должен идти отдельной темой - собственно и [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/784137/213987) есть подходящий, просто не внесён в рубрикатор книг, надо добавить.

А вот что делать с html и css? Дать их единым списком книг или оставить двумя разными? И так неплохо и эдак - давайте решим, как лучше.

У нас уже есть два древних вопроса от 2011 года - так что можно практически без усилий просто внести отдельными строчками.

Можно и влить из одного вопроса в другой (кто этим будет заниматься?), так как темы достаточно близкие.

Давайте пожалуй устроим голосовалку по этому вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно дубликатить к старым вопросам, в которых много субъективных ответов. Лучше создать новый вопрос, с одним Community Wiki ответом, и выдерживать формат простого списка, без субъективных оценок и лирических отступлений.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте внесём отдельными вопросами [книги по html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/213987) и [книги по css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/8516/213987). Из первого вопроса постепенно перенесём во второй всё, что относится к css.

Аргументы "за":

- Темы близкие, но вполне отдельные - поэтому пусть и идут отдельными списками книг